# Take screenshot on Assertion in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

The below is my assertion.

```
Assert.assertEquals(securityQuestionPage.UserName.getText().toString(),BaseClass.unsuccessfulpassword);
```

I wanted to make the test case fail/pass based on the result of Assertion..

if assertion is failed:

```
test.fail("description", takescreenshot)
```

if assertion is passed

```
test.pass("passed",takeScreenshot)
```

without using if statement, can I have assertion like `ternary` operator.

Anything like this?

```
Assert.AsserEquals(locator.getText(), expectedMessage,test.pass(""),test.fail())
```

Comment: Could You explain, what are You trying to achieve, to take a screenshot if test fails? or?

Comment: securityquestionPage.actualerrorMessage == securityquestionPage.expectederrorMessage ? test.pass("Error Message is matched", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreen()).build()):test.fail("Error Message is not matched", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreen()).build());           Trying this way, that comparing two text is equal then it is passed, else fail. But it is not workign

Comment: But in both cases trying to screenshot? Why aren't You trying to do this via "interface ITestListener", and create screenshot on implemenation of public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result);?

Comment: I did not have much knowledge about ITestlisteners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **try-catch** block :

```
try{
 Assert.assertEquals(securityQuestionPage.UserName.getText().toString(),BaseClass.unsuccessfulpassword);  

// Now if the above line is correct then flow will not go to catch block followed by line just after this line.
 test.pass("passed",takeScreenshot)
}

catch(Exception e){
    test.fail("description", takescreenshot)
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, considering that an assert failure generates an error (not an exception) which is already handled by testng.